# How to import CSS files into webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, webpack-2

According to the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-css/#importing-css), CSS file should just be `import`ed.

I am just starting with `webpack` and tried to import a CSS file but I get a message about a module missing:

```
D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog>webpack --display-error-details
Hash: 0cabc1049cbcbdb8d134
Version: webpack 2.6.1
Time: 74ms
   Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
build.js  2.84 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./webpack/entry.js 47 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in ./webpack/entry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'navbar.css' in 'D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack'
resolve 'navbar.css' in 'D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\package.json (relative path: ./webpack)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\package.json (relative path: ./webpack)
    resolve as module
      D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dropbox\dev\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dropbox\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules
        using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/navbar.css)
            as directory
              D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules\navbar.css doesn't exist
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules\navbar.css doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules\navbar.css.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules\navbar.css.json doesn't exist
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\node_modules]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\node_modules]
[D:\Dropbox\node_modules]
[D:\node_modules]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules\navbar.css]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules\navbar.css]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules\navbar.css.js]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules\navbar.css.json]
 @ ./webpack/entry.js 1:0-21
```

`webpack` is ran against the following `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'webpack/entry.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
    rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
        }]
  }
}
```

I initially thought (before using `--display-error-details`) that this was due to some problems with the path structure (specifically forward vs. backward slashes) but then moved `navbar.css` into the root of the folder `webpack` - same issue.

The detailed error shows that the CSS file is sought after in `nodes_module` (which is hunted down though all the directories tree). Why? **How should I then import a file which is in `webpack/static/css/myfile.css` relative to the location of `webpack.config.js`?**

Note: the same issue exists when trying `require` instead of `import`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have to import them like any JavaScript module. That means, when the imported file is neither a relative path (starting with `../` or `./`), nor an absolute path (starting with `/`), it is resolved as a module. By default webpack will look for modules in the `node_modules` directory (in the current directory and all parent directories). This is the same behaviour that [Node.js uses](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

To import `webpack/static/css/myfile.css` in `webpack/entry.js` you have to use a relative path.

```
import './static/css/myfile.css';
```

If you don't want to use a relative path, you can change the directories that webpack uses to find a module with the [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) or you can use [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias).

---

In your webpack config you also defined both `module.rules` and `module.loaders`. When webpack sees `module.rules` it ignores `module.loaders` completely, so your `babel-loader` wouldn't be used. You should only use `module.rules`.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for both information. I think that `webpack` is really nice but the docs are not extraordinary - especially for someone who is not fluent in JS.

Comment: @WoJ  i am facing the same erro from the last 2 days and unable to resolve that  issue can you pls answer to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63396828/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-10-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-t

Comment: and also this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63449399/css-file-is-not-importing

Comment: @AliRaza: I will not be of much help - having moved to more opaque but simpler frameworks (they use webpack internally but I do not see the magic behind)

Answer (score 1):

@Aakash try adding sideEffects: true to css-loader rule like this:

```
test: /\.css$/
sideEffects: true,
use: [...]
```

Looks like webpack treats project css files like a dead code.
Found this workaround at cra config.

Comment: It works. But what does it do ? can you explain a little bit more ?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason; nothing worked for me so I added the `css` file to my list in `entry`:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  entry: ["./src/style.css", "./src/index.js"]
  // ...
}
```