# Webpack Mini CSS Extract Plugin - What's the point of extracting CSS?

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm using the [Mini CSS Extract Plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) to split my CSS into its own file in my `dist` folder of my webpack project.

My `webpack.config.js` file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "style.css"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

When I `npm run build`, this builds the file `style.css` in my `dist` folder, which is identical to my `style.css` file in my `src` folder. I have to include

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
```

in the head of `index.html` in the `dist` folder for this to work. So my question is - **what's the point of extracting the CSS like this?** If the `style.css` file in the `src` folder is identical to the `style.css` file in the `dist` folder, and I have to include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

in the head of my HTML, I don't understand what the advantage is of doing things this way, even though the [Webpack Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/) states

> Note that you can, and in most cases should, split your CSS for better
>   load times in production.

Comment: `Mini CSS Extract Plugin: This plugin extract CSS into separate files. It creates a CSS file per JS file which contains CSS`

Comment: Sometimes you need to import css inside a js file, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44474869/6836839

Comment: css-modules: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Comment: if you are going to have all your css inside one file and include it in `index.html` then you don't need it

Comment: Thanks for the help and resources, @btzr

Answer (score 8):

This allows to cache CSS. 
You can also get a **Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC)**.
 *FOUC happens because the browser takes a while to load JavaScript and the styles would be applied only then.* 
Separating CSS to a file of its own avoids the problem by letting the browser to manage it separately.