# NativeScript resolution specific css (eg page.minWH600.css) not applied when using webpack

Tags: nativescript

As I added webpack to my NativeScript iOS app to bundle it in preparation for release, I discovered that the various some-page.minWH600.css "qualifier" files I was using to target different screen resolutions are no longer loading. (See [NativeScript docs for supporting multiple screen sizes using qualifiers](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/supporting-multiple-screens))

I then refactored a bit to test for small vs medium vs large tablet screens, planning to add a .css file programmatically via...

```
if (mediumScreen) page.addCssFile(app.minWH600.css);
```

...but discovered due to the bundling of pages in webpack, page.addCssFile() doesn't work either.

**Does anyone have another solution to add css classes to support different screen resolutions that works with webpack?**

I can think of the obvious: using many getViewById() calls and adding either NS/js properties and or css styles (or a css class) to each view, but that's laborious and kludgey...

I'd prefer to somehow redefine the relevant css classes on the fly like I was able to before bundling with webpack, but I don't know if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, because someone else may have to solve this someday, I came up with two workarounds.

1. Simply redefining the class using:

   if (mediumScreen) page.addCss(".class {font-size:18 }, .class2 {font-size: 14}");

Oddly enough that works, even though page.addCssFile() does not. The disadvantage is that the css presentation is buried in the code and this is less maintainable.

2. By using the "nativescript-dom" plugin to gather all the views by class and defining a function to add ".classTablet" to all views containing ".class", I was able to keep all the css together in one css file for easier maintenance. I simply added the class for the larger screen size to that file and use:

   if (tabletScreen) addSizeClass("welcomeButton","welcomeButtonTabletSize");

which calls the global function:

```
require("nativescript-dom"); // must install this nativescript plugin 
addSizeClass = function(className, newSizeClassname) {
    // note page is a global variable and is set in onNavigatedTo
    var items = page.getElementsByClassName(className); //getElementsByClassName() is from nativescript-dom plugin
    items.forEach((item) => { item.className += " " + newSizeClassname; }); //define and maintain a new size class in app.css   
}
```

3. Of course, better yet might be configuring NativeScript webpack to be smarter. But I am no webpack configuration guru.

Comment: Got this answer back on slack too... 
Well, there are some possibilities to do that. First, I think you can require css file as you would do with js file (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474484/how-to-import-css-files-into-webpack). Second, you can bypass webpack and simply copy css files in the bundle. Third, you can wrap your css-classes inside another class, for example `page-400`, `page-600` and `page-800` and then add the class programatically on the outer layout of your page using `layout.className = pageWidth >= 800 ? 'page-800' : pageWidth >=600 ? 'page-600' : 'page-400'`