# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' when bundling a css file

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I need help with importing an external css file from a library. My current webpack config for css files is thus (no plugins for css):

```
{
      test: /\.css$/i,
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
},
```

I am using webpack for SSR. In my .jsx file I am importing css as follows:

```
import 'remirror/styles/all.css';
```

When I start webpack, everything at first seems fine:
[image]

But then suddenly there is that disturbing error:

```
C:\Users\User\desktop\projects\chat-app\node_modules\remirror\styles\all.css:4
.remirror-editor-wrapper {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.remirror/styles/all.css (C:\Users\User\desktop\projects\chat-app\dist\server.generated.js:645:18)

Node.js v17.5.0
```

I have gone through several stackoverflow questions and thought maybe my webpack config is not correct, so I tried following in webpack config:

```
{
                test: /\.css$/i,
                oneOf: [
                  {
                    include: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                      "style-loader",
                      { loader: "css-loader", options: { modules: true } }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    use: [
                      "style-loader",
                      "css-loader"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
},
```

and also:

```
{
            test: /\.css$/i,
            include: /node_modules/,
            // use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            use: [
                { loader: "style-loader" },
                { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } }
            ]
},
```

and:

```
{
        test: /\.css$/i,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
},
```

But none of the above css configs were helpful. Could someone please suggest me a solution?

Comment: The error makes me believe you try to compile your CSS files as JavaScript. That can't work, CSS is not JS. `import` is used to import ES6 modules, not style sheets.

Comment: @knittl I have also been thinking so but I had believed webpack must distinguish it as css because of the configs. Is there a way to "notify" webpack that it is css?

Comment: @knittl hi! I am still having this problem! In React we can import css, but why not in webpack? Why this syntax doesn’t work in webpack? If you have any suggestions, it would be great.

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the leading `./` when importing the CSS file? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44474484/112968

Comment: @knittl oh yes i tried it, it doesn’t work, because it is an external stylesheet. thanks for suggestion!